# Open MP Schedules - Finding the best argument for a loop

Tags: c, for-loop, openmp, schedule

I'm having trouble understanding an assigment I'm doing for my *Parallel Computing* course. The problem in question is this:

> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
>     int arg = ...
>     compute(arg);
> }
> ```
>
> Where the execution time of `compute()` is proportional to the value of its argument. We want to parallelize this loop using OpenMP, with one of the schedules `static`, `dynamic` or `guided`. Find an example of an expression for `arg` (i.e. complete line 2) so that the best schedule to use would be:
>
> 1. static
> 2. dynamic
> 3. guided
>
> Explain your answers.

I don't have any problem understanding the OpenMP Schedules, but I'm having trouble finding any sort of information that can help me decide which arguments to use, and why.

The curriculum is of no use, and I haven't had any luck with Google.

I understand if people "don't want to give me homework solutions", but a solid pointer in the right direction would be nice. Simply put, how can I evaluate which argument to use for any of the Schedules?

Comment: So presumably you've done what any of the rest of us would have done by now, you've written a little bit of code to experiment with and buggered around with various stabs in the dark, gathered some data and started to make some deductions ?  Computing is not a spectator sport ....

Comment: No one except you has mentioned anything about a spectator sport. If you don't want to help, that's fine, but you could do without that accusing tone.

Comment: Why didn't the course ask you to consider auto as well?  Is it limited to OpenMP 2? With the information provided, you may infer that the slowest loop iteration takes nearly twice as long as the average, thus it may be worth testing various choices of schedule and chunk.  Additional information is needed to guess whether guided might be best, but the answer is still likely to be problem and platform dependent.

Comment: The assignment is quite big, so it's possible that the instructor only chose the "most relevant". And as far as I know, we're using OpenMP 4 (201307).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are asking you to come up with 3 different things 'arg' could be to suit each of the 3 scheduling methods.

Keep in mind they have told you that the processing time is proportional to the int value of arg.

So for static scheduling, arg must always be the same number, so the processing time is always identical. Thus something like `arg=10;`

For dynamic scheduling, this would be when arg is changing value, so something like `arg=rand();` As that would result in randomly different time for each compute.

For guiding scheduling, maying something like `arg = i / 10;` because arg will remain static for a while at each value, while still dynamically changing through values.

Comment: And this is a perfect example on how I'm able to have something right in front of me, and still not see it. Thank you!

Comment: For extra marks, you should do some benchmarking (or look at standard OpenMP benchmarks like EPCC) to investigate the overheads of the different schedules. Depending on the amount of imbalance, you might find that schedule(static,1) can outperform schedule(dynamic) for the triangular case... (The point being that the performance model your advisor is using is inaccurate :-))